# Dos hojas de Excel en PDF

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo en una macro el siguiente código para convertir mi hoja1 de excel en pdf.

```
 With Sheets("Hoja1")
    With .PageSetup
      .Orientation = xlLandscape
      .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
      .Zoom = 60
    End With
    
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=RutaArchivo, OpenAfterPublish:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, IncludeDocProperties:=True
    
    End With
```

Necesito ahora incluir la Hoja3 tambien y obviar la Hoja2. Quedando en total dos hojas de PDF con una hoja del excel cada una.
¿Cómo podria hacerlo?

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Con el grabador de macros puedes hacer esto fácilmente y adaptar el código a tus necesidades. Pruébalo

Comment: Ya lo he intentado, pero en la opción de imprimir en PDF de excel, no me da la opción de legir las hojas que quiero imprimir, excluyendo a la hoja 2.

Comment: selecciona las hojas que quieras, saltando la hoja 2, y dale a guardar como--pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

podrías crear un array con el nombre de las hojas que deaseas guardar
Ojo, guarda todas las hojas del Array en el mismo pdf, o sea, no crea un pdf con cada hoja

```
'selecionamos la hoja a guardar si es una sola hoja
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATOS").Select
'Si quieres guardar varias hojas podrías hacer
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("DATOS", "Hoja2", "Hoja5", "Calendario")).Select

'pasamos el valor almacenado en Nombre_Archivo concatenado con tu texto "Planificación"
NombreArchivo = "Planificación." & Nombre_Archivo
'creamos la ruta donde se almacenará el fichero, en éste caso, en "Mis Documentos"
RutaArchivo = "C:\Users\" & usuario & "\Documents\" & NombreArchivo & ".pdf"

'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
'Se guarda el fichero
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=RutaArchivo
```

El código es parte de una respuesta que hice anteriormente, aquí tienes el enlace:
[Respuesta a guardar hojas excel como pdf con vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453553/guardar-hoja-de-excel-como-pdf-tomando-el-nombre-de-la-hoja-de-una-varibale-as%C3%AD/453598#453598)