# Guardar hoja de excel como pdf tomando el nombre de la hoja de una varibale así como el usuario actual del sistema

Tags: excel, vba

recienteme solicité vuestra ayuda para ocultar celdas.

Ahora necesitaría guardar el fichero de excel como pdf, pero me gustaría que lo hiciera de forma autónoma, tomando el nombre de la hoja con una pregunta al usuario y además, agregar el nombre de dicho usuario al nombre de dicha hoja

He buscado por internet y he conseguido éste código, se podría agregar lo que pido ?

```
Sub GuardarHojasComoPDF()

'------------------------------------------pdf2
    Dim NombreArchivo As String

    Sheets("DATOS").Activate
    Sheets("DATOS").Select

    'Create and assign variables
    'Dim saveLocation As String
    NombreArchivo = "Planificación"

    'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NombreArchivo

    '------------------------------------------pdf2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver si te sirve ésto

```
Sub GuardarHojasComoPDF()

    '------------------------------------------pdf2
    Dim NombreArchivo As String
    Dim RutaArchivo As String
    Dim usuario As String
    'tomamos el usuario del sistema
    usuario = Application.UserName

    Sheets("DATOS").Activate
    Sheets("DATOS").Select

    'Cargamos Dialog que pregunte al usuario el nombre del archivo a guardar y lo almacenamos en la variable Nombre_Archivo
    Nombre_Archivo = Application.InputBox("Introduzca un sub-nombre para el archivo", "Sub-Nombre")

    'selecionamos la hoja a guardar
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATOS").Select
    'Si quieres guardar varias hojas podrías hacer
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("DATOS", "Hoja2", "Hoja3")).Select

    'pasamos el valor almacenado en Nombre_Archivo concatenado con tu texto "Planificación"
    NombreArchivo = "Planificación." & Nombre_Archivo
    'creamos la ruta donde se almacenará el fichero, en éste caso, en "Mis Documentos"
    RutaArchivo = "C:\Users\" & usuario & "\Documents\" & NombreArchivo & ".pdf"

    'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
    'Se guarda el fichero
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=RutaArchivo

    '------------------------------------------pdf2

End Sub
```

Comment: Guaooo!!!, muchas gracias, me funciona. Perfect. Thanks